# Django WizardView with checkboxes in Form causes "ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using a WizardView in which the second Form is:

```
FRAME_AND_ALIGNMENT_CHOICES = ["Align Derailleur Hanger", "Basic Clean", 
"Install Front Basket"]

class RepairsForm(Form):
    frame_and_alignment = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=FRAME_AND_ALIGNMENT_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

I have a WizardView like this:

```
NEW_ORDER_TEMPLATES = {'0': 'app/create_customer.html', '1': 'app/repairs.html'}

class CustomerWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [NEW_ORDER_TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        customer_id = process_customer(form_list[0])
        process_repairs(form_list[1], customer_id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index'))
```

Finally, here's my template for the second form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {{ wizard.form.frame_and_alignment }}
{#    {{ wizard.form.as_p }}#}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The first page of the form fills out fine, but when I hit submit to proceed to this template and form, I get a ValueError on the statement `{{ wizard.form.frame_and_alignment }}` that reads "too many values to unpack (expected 2)". My guess is that it has to do with the MultipleChoiceField or something.

**EDIT Here's the traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_order/

Django Version: 1.7.2
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.formtools',
 'app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/app/templates/app/repairs.html, error at line 10
   too many values to unpack (expected 2)
   1 : {% extends "app/base.html" %}


   2 : 


   3 : {% block content %}


   4 : 


   5 : {%  if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}


   6 : 


   7 : <form action="" method="post">


   8 :     {% csrf_token %}


   9 :     {{ wizard.management_form }}


   10 :      {{ wizard.form.frame_and_alignment }} 


   11 : {#    {{ wizard.form.as_p }}#}


   12 :     <input type="submit" value="Save" />


   13 : </form>


   14 : 


   15 : 


   16 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  80.         content = template.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  93.             output = force_text(output)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  83.                     s = six.text_type(s)
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  508.         return self.as_widget()
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  560.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  739.         return self.get_renderer(name, value, attrs, choices).render()
File "/Users/johnking/workspace/rice-bikes/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  687.             choice_value, choice_label = choice

Exception Type: ValueError at /create_order/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback?

Comment: @Alasdair Added the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) should be a list of iteratables of two items.

You could do either:

```
FRAME_AND_ALIGNMENT_CHOICES = [
    ("Align Derailleur Hanger", "Align Derailleur Hanger")
    ("Basic Clean", "Basic Clean"),
    ("Install Front Basket", "Install Front Basket"),
]
```

Or use a list comprehension to reduce duplication:

```
FRAME_AND_ALIGNMENT_CHOICES = [(c, c) for c in ["Align Derailleur Hanger", "Basic Clean", "Install Front Basket"]]
```

Or, you might want to store a code in the database, and display the full description to the user:

```
FRAME_AND_ALIGNMENT_CHOICES = [
    ("derailleur", "Align Derailleur Hanger"),
    ("clean", Basic Clean"),
    ("basket", "Install Front Basket"),
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I find Django's docs a little hard to read. E.g. I couldn't just look up CheckboxSelectMultiple, but instead had to read through the docs for all widgets like it's a tutorial. But anyway I see where it says that now and I thank you!